# jVectormap - change default country color

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

i am trying to change the default light-grey default color jVectormap uses for displaying any of the countries on the world map. Additionally, it would be great to know if the country border color can be changed as well?

I am running v2.0.3 and am using the standard world-map.

Reference:
[World Map Sample](http://jvectormap.com/examples/markers-world/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like there are quite a few changes in syntax from V1.x.x to v2.x.x., at long last the following line of code managed to change the default country and hover color of whatever regional map the client is using.

`regionStyle: { initial: { fill: '#d2d6de' }, hover: { fill: '#A0D1DC' } },`

Hope that helps someone who has the same problems as me.